# Module not specified in Android Studio 3.0.1

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

Just migrated to Android Studio 3. When I was tying to embed a unity app within android [using this](https://medium.com/@davidbeloosesky/embedded-unity-within-android-app-7061f4f473a) I keep running to ***module not specified*** error. 
Note that this procedure used to work just fine before I migrated to Android Studio 3.

```
apply plugin: com.android.application

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "yenettaapp.beblocky"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }}dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])


    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile project(":BeBlockyMobi-debug")
    compile project(":my_bebot_plugin-release")
    implementation 'com.github.ericwlange:AndroidJSCore:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.blockly.android:blocklylib-vertical:0.9-beta.20170824'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: Show your `build.gradle` files.

Comment: @JaredBurrows Just added the gradle file

Comment: Is `BeBlockyMobi-debug` and `my_bebot_plugin-release` in your `settings.gradle`?